# does NFS overrides TCP keepalive time?

Tags: linux, nfs, tcp

1. NFS server somehow disconnect
2. NFS client detect server is disconnected
3. client tries to reconnect
4. server reappears and reconnect successfully

it seems that TCP keepalive, connection timeout is doing something  but the default keepalive time, which I found in /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ is 7200

so i thought tcp keepalive time is overridden by NFS

current problem is that when NFS client takes few minutes to detect server and showing message below, we'd like to shorten this time(No3 from above).

"nfs: server  not responding, still trying"

we measured the polling time,

1. 24sec
2. 72sec （24sec+(24sec*2=48sec)）
3. 16sec （72sec+(48sec*2=96sec)）
4. 360sec （168sec+(96sec*2=192sec)）
5. 660sec （+300sec）
6. 960sec （+300sec）

24 -> 48 -> 96 -> 192 -> 300 -> 300

does anyone know where you can find this '300'?
or is this because of some other issue rather than TCP keepalive time?

Comment: * we already touched 
kernel parameters from /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_retries2

Comment: Doesn't the NFS protocol itself detect the absence of the server, instead of relying on the underlying TCP keepalive?

Comment: NFS over TCP is what we are using. so the protocol is TCP

Comment: No, NFS is also a protocol, which can use TCP or UDP as transport layer. TCP is an OSI level 4 protocol, NFS is a higher level protocol (one could argue that it's level 5 but there are different opinions about this). TCP in turn uses IP as its underlying protocol. So saying "the protocol is TCP" is al bit short-sighted. So it's possible that NFS is doing some sort of keepalive handshake (i.e. sending TCP data packets to and fro with specific content) which has nothing to do with TCP keepalive.

Comment: so is there something that configures TCP keepalive on NFS? sorry for the basical question. thanks

Comment: I guess NFS will use the system defaults, do `grep . /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive*`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, NFS client does override keepalive settings -- it derives them from 
'timeo' mount option.  see http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/sunrpc/xprtsock.c for low-level detail.